"Unable to import module 'handlers': cannot import name 'model_validate' from 'pydantic' .... "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
from pydantic import model_validate

it is not working and is resulting in the error :
"Function Error: Unhandled, Log Result: null, Payload: {"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handlers': cannot import name 'model_validate' from 'pydantic' (/var/task/pydantic/__init__.py)", "errorType": "Runt
ime.ImportModuleError"

I have migrated to v2 and tried importing it from sub-libraries but didn't found the solution
